# Can't save "Solution Badges" on VSCommands 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

My screen is too small to see the save button on Solution Badges windows as you could see. I can't even scroll or go to the end.

Someone gives me an advice to how to bypass its "error".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be fixed in the next release, sorry for the problem.
In the future, you can contact me directly at jarek@squaredinfinity.com